# Tokens created in for loop are not being passed to secondary script

Tags: windows, batch-file, token

I will start off by saying that I am horribly new at this. Upon researching, I have run into a lot of examples that include far more complex scripts than what I am currently attempting to do.

This script prompts the user to create/delete/cancel a user/group from a file list while calling child scripts. (I am to use at least 3 total scripts with a recommended amount of 5)

The file being read looks similar to this: (Departments occasionally repeating, 3 columns)

--

EMPLOYEES

--

> Name            employeeID      Department
>
> aaaaa           AAAAA           Alpha
>
> bbbbb           BBBBB           Beta
>
> ccccc           CCCCC           Omega
>
> ddddd           DDDDD           Beta

***ScriptA*** is as follows (Runs Smoothly, the child scripts are my issue - I think)

```
::This script reads a provided file and creates or deletes users, groups, and folders.
:MENU
CHOICE /C CRX /M "Create or Remove? To cancel, hit X."
REM @ECHO OFF
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO CREATE
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO DELETE
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO END

:CREATE
CALL MakeUsersandGroups.cmd
GOTO END

:DELETE
CALL RemoveUsersandGroups.cmd

:END
ECHO Exiting
PAUSE
```

***Script B*** MakeUsersandGroups.cmd is as follows

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P usrfile="Extract names from which file? "

::Make groups

FOR /F "tokens=1-3 skip=4" %%A IN (%usrfile%) DO GOTO GROUP

:GROUP

CALL mkgroup.cmd %%A %%B %%C
```

Script B appears to run smoothly, however the %%A %%B %%C does not properly transfer over to the called .bat file. I was taught in class that the tokens convert to numbers %1 %2 %3.

***Script C*** (mkgroup.cmd) is as follows so far

```
::Create users and groups using columns stated by variables in caller script.
:CHECKGROUP
NET LOCALGROUP %3 | FIND /i "%3" > NUL && GOTO GROUPEXISTS
NET LOCALGROUP %3 /ADD

:GROUPEXISTS

GOTO USER
:USER

NET USER | FIND /i "%2" > NUL && GOTO USEREXISTS
NET USER %1 %2 /ADD
NET LOCALGROUP %3 %2 /ADD
GOTO FOLDER

:USEREXISTS
NET LOCALGROUP %3 | FIND /i "%2" > NUL && GOTO FOLDER
NET LOCALGROUP %3 %2 /ADD

:FOLDER
FIND /i "C:/home/%2" > NUL && GOTO CONTINUE
MKDIR C:/home/%2

:CONTINUE
```

THIS is where I have encountered errors. 
When it runs without ECHO OFF active I get the following in cmd

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 skip=4" %A IN (newhirestest.txt) DO GOTO GROUP
GOTO GROUP
CALL mkgroup.cmd %A %B %C
NET LOCALGROUP     | FIND /i "" 1>NUL && GOTO GROUPEXISTS
NET LOCALGROUP /ADD
The syntax of this command is:

NET LOCALGROUP
[groupname [/COMMENT:"text"]] [/DOMAIN]
               groupname {/ADD [/COMMENT:"text"] | /DELETE} [/DOMAIN]
               groupname name [...] {/ADD | /DELETE} [/DOMAIN]

GOTO USER
NET USER     | FIND /i C 1>NUL && GOTO USEREXISTS
FIND: Parameter format not correct
NET USER B C /ADD

the command completed successfully ::no actually, it made users of my variable names

NET LOCALGROUP C /ADD
The specified local group already exists.

GOTO FOLDER
FIND /i "C:home/C"     1>NUL && GOTO CONTINUE

::infinite type lock, had to ^C, Y to exit
```

It is very obvious to me that my tokens/variables are not transferring correctly, however I can not figure why or how to fix it: based on my notes from class, this has been done correctly.

There are two similar other scripts for removing and they seems to be running without errors.

Any advisory would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Scripts A and B work as planned now.
I am running into a never ending input screen for my create file (script C).
The delete scripts work as planned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems here.

The way to check the ERRORLEVEL value returned from `CHOICE` command is wrong. You may entirely avoid the series of `IF` commands and directly use such an ERRORLEVEL in a `GOTO` command, that is a simpler solution:

```
:MENU
:OPTION-255
CHOICE /C CRX /M "Create or Remove? To cancel, hit X."
GOTO OPTION-%ERRORLEVEL%

:OPTION-1 CREATE
CALL MakeUsersandGroups.cmd
GOTO END

:OPTION-2 DELETE
CALL RemoveUsersandGroups.cmd

:OPTION-3 END
:OPTION-0
ECHO Exiting
PAUSE
```

The other problem is that you are *not* exporting the `%%A %%B %%C` `FOR` parameters *in the same `FOR` context*, because the `GOTO GROUP` command cancel the `FOR`. You must change it by a `CALL GROUP` command instead. After that, you may use a simple trick in order to get the tokens of the *active* `FOR` command: just active another `FOR` with *any* (unused) token:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 skip=4" %%A IN (%usrfile%) DO CALL GROUP
rem Other code here
GOTO :EOF


:GROUP
FOR %%a IN (x) DO CALL mkgroup.cmd %%A %%B %%C
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. I am encountering one problem now in the create script. All others function as planned.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in MakeUsersandGroups.cmd (script B).

`For` loop variables only exist within the scope of the loop, so when you use a `goto` to leave the loop, `%%A`, `%%B`, and `%%C` are destroyed and you end up passing nothing to mkgroup.cmd.

You can get around this by sticking the call to mkgroup.cmd in the `for` loop itself:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET /P usrfile="Extract names from which file? "

::Make groups
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 skip=4" %%A IN (%usrfile%) DO CALL mkgroup.cmd %%A %%B %%C
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, in ScriptA

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO CREATE
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO DELETE
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO END
```

must be reversed.

The `if errorlevel` syntax is interpreted as "if errorlevel is n **or greater than n** dothis" so since `3` is normlly greater than `1`, the first branch will be taken.

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO END
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO DELETE
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO CREATE
```

Should work as intended.

Comment: Errorlevels 255 and 0 should also be accounted for.

Comment: Oddly, this did not work in my program. It would only call the create file for any of the error levels.